# How to change Facebook 'Like' button to 'Recommend' button

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I have a snippet to create a 'Like' button for our news site:

```
<iframe id="likeButton" src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href="
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

However, to make it work properly, because the button posted an error saying the button was on an invalid URL address, I added a bit of jQuery to tweak the URL like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        var imageFile = $('#likeButton').attr( 'src');
        eval("imageFile = imageFile +"+"window.location.href;");     
        eval("$('#likeButton').attr( 'src', function(){return imageFile +"+"window.location.href;});");
    });
</script>
```

That works as far as I can tell.

I want to change the button from like to recommend and know from the Facebook site that I need to append an attribute of action=recommend to the URL.  But as a newbie I've been unable to add it so it works. How can I add attributes to the URL?

Comment: you may also need to strip out the original action=like parameter before adding the action=recommend. The default widget code from FB contains action=like in the querystring. (meant to post this under the answer from Josh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have no business calling `eval` in this case.  It is very rare that eval is ever needed, and it should be avoided at all costs.  Having said that, look at the following code.   I am simply building the new `src` attribute using standard query string syntax to add your new action value, and then I set it.  Pretty self-explanatory...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var iframe = $("#likeButton");
  var newSrc = iframe.attr("src");
  newSrc += encodeURIComponent(location.href);
  newSrc += "&action=recommend";

  iframe.attr("src", newSrc);
});
```

If anything in there does not make sense to you, feel free to ask and I will explain further.

Comment: This should work, yes, but might I suggest you change your `var img` to some other name? `#likeButton` is an `<iframe>`, not an `<img>`

Comment: That's brilliant. I'm still getting to grips with basic string manipulation so I appreciate your help.